# Is a car odometer reading protected by MAC?

Tags: mac

I knew the reading on a car odometer can be easily modified with the help of some softwares. But isn't there MAC to protect the reading from being modified?

Comment: Where will be the key stored? How will the service read the odometer? What will happen if the key is erased? and some other problems..., All of these can be solved, however, will add to cost.

Comment: In general almost certainly no.

Comment: By using MAC, we need *to share* a (secret) key. Anyway, as it was commented by Kelalaka, what is your threat/adversarial model?

Comment: This sounds like a question about how cars protect their data - you might have more luck on an automotive message board.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is asking for a specific form of **trade secret**, which the community does not have the ability to answer.